How to handle additional parameters for different implementations of an interface in Java?
I am working on a Spring Boot project where I have a Notifier interface with a send(String message) method. Different implementations of Notifier, such as FCMNotifier and SNSNotifier, require additional parameters to send notifications (e.g., tokens, topics, etc.).
Here is an example of my interface and two implementations:
public interface Notifier {
    void send(String message);
}

@Component
public class FCMNotifier implements Notifier {

    @Override
    public void send(String message) {
        // Use token to send message via FCM
       // need token

    }
}

@Component
public class SNSNotifier implements Notifier {

    @Override
    public void send(String message) {

        // Use topicArn to send message via SNS
       // need topicArn
    }
}

As you can see, each implementation requires additional parameters (token for FCMNotifier, and topicArn for SNSNotifier). I want to make this design more flexible and avoid tightly coupling the parameters to specific implementations.
My Question:
What is the best way to handle such additional parameters for different implementations in a scalable and maintainable way?
Should I use something like a Context object to pass parameters dynamically? Or are there better design patterns to solve this?
Should I add a builder to handle common requests instead?
I tried using both the Builder pattern and the Decorator pattern to improve flexibility and scalability. I expected the Builder pattern to help in constructing notifications with different parameters (like tokens or topics) dynamically, and the Decorator pattern to allow me to layer additional behaviors (e.g., logging or retry mechanisms) around the notification process. However, I am not sure if this is the right approach or if there are better patterns or practices I should consider for this use case.

They should be constructor parameters for the implementation classes.  Don't over-complicate things.

Sounds like they don't have a common interface if additional parameters are needed.
My first thought is: Don't overcomplicate it.
If you make the common method send(), without parameters, you can pass the different parameter types into a constructor as member variables.   Each type of Notifier can handle them as they wish.
The downside to this approach is that you need to create an instance every time you want to send a notification.
Java developers love patterns and object hierarchies.   Sometimes we get carried away.   Do something simple and only add complexity when necessary.

Thank you for your thoughtful response! I really appreciate your advice on keeping it simple. I ended up taking a similar approach by pulling tokens from a repository and implementing the functionality that way. It works effectively and avoids unnecessary complexity. Thanks again for the guidance!

I would combine generics with polymorphism like so:
public interface Notifier<D> {
    void send(D data);
}

public interface CommonNotifierData {
    String getMessage();
}

public class FCMData implements CommonNotifierData {
    private Token token; //I am not certain for token's data type, so I just used 'Token' as a symbol. Change to your needs.
    //Implement CommonNotifierData here, token getter, etc...
}

public class SNSData implements CommonNotifierData {
    private TopicArn topicArn; //I am not certain for topicArn's data type, so I just used 'TopicArn' as a symbol. Change to your needs.
    //Implement CommonNotifierData here, topicArn getter, etc...
}

@Component
public class FCMNotifier implements Notifier<FCMData> {

    @Override
    public void send(final FCMData data) {
        //Use 'data.getMessage()', 'data.getToken()', etc...
    }
}

@Component
public class SNSNotifier implements Notifier<SNSData> {

    @Override
    public void send(final SNSData data) {
        //Use 'data.getMessage()', 'data.getTopicArn()', etc...
    }
}


In case a client would need to accept any CommonNotifierData sending Notifier they would just use a Notifier<? super CommonNotifierData>.
This way I believe decouples the Notifier with its data to send. In my opinion this is useful because as far as I understand Notifiers implement the functionality of sending the data, whereas data itself is a standalone object (because they don't implement any kind of functionality and can be plain beans for example). As an example, you don't need to change the FCM sending functionality each time a token changes. On the other hand, in case sending the data can not logically be decoupled from the notifier (on a per instance basis) then I would suggest @duffymo's answer.
Note:
I know that almost always simpler is better (as @duffymo suggests), but this case doesn't seem already complex, at least for my eyes. Also, I am not really familiar with Spring, but it seems unrelated here, at least as far as what my answer tries to address (and after reading some basic things on Spring's @Component annotation).

You need to store those additional parameter in classes that implements Notifier.
If you need to acquire them for each call of send method, those implementation should be responsible for that.

If the interface looks like that, and you can't change it, implementation-specific 'extra data' has to be already available in the object via some other means. From a perspective of encapsulation (invariants, etc.), the most object-oriented solution is to make sure that the data has been made available via the constructor:
@Component
public class FCMNotifier implements Notifier {
    private Object token;

    public FCMNotifier(Object token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(String message) {
        // Use this.token to send message via FCM
    }
}

This usually opens a second question of where that extra data comes from. If it comes from a configuration file or similar, the design may be appropriate.
If, on the other hand, the extra data also has to be extracted from run-time values, then you may need to reconsider the design of the abstraction (here, the interface) itself.

I think in your case it would be better to define the interface accepting another parameter. For any notification you need a message and you need a destination. You can define a destination object or a marker interface.
You can also define an object like Notification which has the message field and the destination field.

I would store the token in a field value of a @Component classes if the value doesn't change over time, and fill in those fields upon constructing the bean.
However if you still want to do it the way you asked, the interface send method can look like this
void send(Object... arguments);
and thus you get a variable number of arguments in both classes.
